# Wobbling wheel, Chevy Malibu LT

Tags: tires, suspension, alignment, malibu, struts

I have a 2007 Chevy Malibu I was driving down the highway and I heard a pop come from the rear passenger side wheel and then it sounded like I had a flat but the tire is now wobbling pretty bad what could’ve happened? I just had new tires put on in the back because they were wearing on the inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like one or more of the wheelnuts or lug nuts have come off and the remaining ones are loose.

Get this checked and have new nuts fitted as necessary. The studs will need checking as well.

Do contact the place that fitted the tires as they may have left them loose. It could, however, be that someone was stealing your rims and were disturbed - might depend on how long ago you have the tires replaced...